# Get list of folders and files in SD card

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I've already accessed SD card, but I'm confused how to get list of folders and files in the SD card root and it's child, can anyone help me?

```
StorageFolder sdCard = (await KnownFolders.RemovableDevices.GetFoldersAsync()).FirstOrDefault();

if (sdCard == null)
{                          
   t1.Text = "Not Found";
}
else
{
  //t1.Text = "Found";
  //here i want to get list folder and files
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150593.aspx) you have nice examples. Basicly you get a [StorageFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder), so you can get list of your items by using [GetItemsAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.getitemsasync.aspx) (files and folders) or directly [GetFilesAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227276) and [GetFoldersAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227280). Simple example:

List of folders:

```
IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> folderList = await sdCard.GetFoldersAsync();
```

List of files:

```
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileList = await sdCard.GetFilesAsync();
```

Note also that to use SD card you have to add *Removable Storage* capability in your *package.appxmanifest* file.

And remember that your App can access only files for which you have declared *File Type Association* (again *package.appxmanifet* file, <kbd>Declarations</kbd> tab), [more at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn611857.aspx):

> What you can access
>
> Your app can only read and write files of file types that the app has registered to handle in the app manifest file.
>
> Your app can also create and manage folders.

Without this, you won't be able to see the files.

Comment: IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileList = await localFolder.GetFilesAsync();
                outputText.AppendLine("Files:");
                foreach (StorageFile files in fileList)
                {
                    outputText.Append(files.Name + "\n");
                }
 t1.Text = outputText.ToString();

but the result of files is empty, so does folder, can you help?

Comment: File Type Association -> what should i fill if i want to read all file type and folder?

Comment: @user3639685 Folders you get all by default, but files only those for which you have specified File Type Association. I doubt you can specify *all* file types.

Comment: hmmm, i try, is emulator folder empty? or maybe any clue? because i try the link you gave and it works, but the folder empty

Comment: @user3639685 In Emulator you have to enable SD card - Tools -> SD card. Have you added capabilities, file type associations? What foler empty, are there any folders/files? What do you mean '*link works but folder empty*'?

Comment: oh sorry, actually i used wrong variable hahaha,,,,, 
it works now,,,
i really appreciate your help, thank you so much